# carrierwave new version image issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, carrierwave

I did try create a new version for my images but always get issue "object name required"
I try many methods but I can not regenerate new version from my images

this is my code

```
Product.all.each do |product|
   product.image.recreate_versions!(:large)
```

end

thanks in advance

Comment: Safe to assume that the Product model has the uploader mounted?

Comment: Also if you can put the error message that'd be helpful, thanks!

Comment: yeah , it has uploader mounted and only have this message "object name required" nothing more .